# Update progress bar from business layer windows app

Tags: winforms, delegates

I have a 3 tiered vb windows application with a progress bar in the ui. Is there an example of how I could call a method in the business layer and update the progress bar in the ui. How do I reference it?

For example if I do businesslayer.domethod()

Then in businesslayer can I can't do ui.progressbar.update as it doesn't know it exists as its in a different assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do ou mean with "3-tiered windows application"? Are the layers phisycally independent? How did you implement inter-layer communication? By you example "busineslayer.dosomething()" it seems that all your layers are in the same machine and you are not using any remoting technique. If your layers are just logical layers in the same machine and process then you can take two approaches:

1) You can pass a call-back delegate to your busineslayer.domethod() method so it can call back the UI to inform progress, or

2) Your busineslayer class can implement some events. Make your UI subscrive your events to get updated.

I would implement the secund approach.